# Is it possible to get scrobbling from information from last.fm API

Tags: last.fm

I am getting information about the track I am listening to from last.fm.. I cannot however get the information about what I am scrobbling from, like you see on you last.fm page: "scrobbling now from spotify"

Does anyone know if this is possible without scraping the user page?

I don't see anything in the API docs - could easily be missing something.

The call I am using to get the now playing track is user.getRecentTracks which you use a attribute on the first song returned (nowplaying="true") to tell if its being played now and there is nothing about what I am listening on there.

Comment: I am pretty certain the answer is no on this one.. if anyone has ever seen "scrobbling now from X" anywhere other than last.fm then at least pop a comment in about it and I can investigate that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: **no**, [Last.fm API](https://www.last.fm/api) doesn't support this feature.

The only way you can get this information is to scrap it from `<div class="scrobblesource">`.